# Azure Powershell : Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Operation "get" is not allowed

Tags: powershell, azure

I logged into to azure powershell using a service principle with a certificate, like this :

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint  $thumbprint -ApplicationId   $applicationid -TenantId $tenant
```

Then I tried to get a azure secret :

```
$b = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name 'AccountKey'
```

But I get an error :

> "get" is not allowed

I thought I gave read access, like this :

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId.Guid
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you given permissions at the vault level to the Service Principal?

Comment: I figured it out . I missed this step :  Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName   $vaultname    -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId  -PermissionsToSecrets Get

Comment: If you are able to, it would be good to make your question an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the correct access policies, give get permissions to the serviceprinciple with Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ServicePrincipalName 'http://payroll.contoso.com' -PermissionsToSecrets Get
```